# OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'restart/snapshot_Quad9_p0000_i00001124.xmf'

Tags: python, grass-gis, simulation

I had fix the code before, but now it got me error like this. I didn't know what's this mean
Titan2D v4.0.0

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simulation.py", line 83, in <module>
    sim=sim.run()
  File "/home/dinar/Downloads/titan2d-v4.0.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/titan/titan.py", line 1125, in run
    self._setCxxTitanSimulation()
  File "/home/dinar/Downloads/titan2d-v4.0.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/titan/titan.py", line 907, in _setCxxTitanSimulation
    check_and_remove_filedir(output_prefix)
  File "/home/dinar/Downloads/titan2d-v4.0.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/titan/titan.py", line 895, in check_and_remove_filedir
    shutil.rmtree(filename)
  File "/home/dinar/Downloads/titan2d-v4.0.0/lib/titan2d_dep/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 252, in rmtree
    onerror(os.remove, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/dinar/Downloads/titan2d-v4.0.0/lib/titan2d_dep/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 250, in rmtree
    os.remove(fullname)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'restart/snapshot_Quad9_p0000_i00001124.xmf'
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that the program doesn't have permission to read or write `restart/snapshot_Quad9_p0000_i00001124.xmf`. You need to make sure it has those permissions using either `chmod` or `chown`.